# NoAppDetectedError - An app was not successfully detected by any available buildpack

Tags: javascript, cloud-foundry

I'm having trouble trying to push my app to the cloud foundry. I keep getting:

```html
Pushing app space-icar-dev to org SPACE / space QMSTOOL-dev as space-qms-pipeline...
Packaging files to upload...
Uploading files...
 170.36 KiB / 170.36 KiB [==========================================================================================================================================================================================] 100.00% 1s 

Waiting for API to complete processing files...

Staging app and tracing logs...
   Downloading nodejs_buildpack_latest...
   Downloading nginx_buildpack...
   Downloading staticfile_buildpack...
   Downloading appmetrics_nodejs8_buildpack...
   Downloading java_buildpack_offline...
   Downloaded appmetrics_nodejs8_buildpack
   Downloading nginx_buildpack_offline...
   Downloaded nodejs_buildpack_latest
   Downloading dotnet_core_buildpack_offline...
   Downloaded java_buildpack_offline
   Downloading r_buildpack...
   Downloaded staticfile_buildpack
   Downloading dotnet_core_buildpack...
   Downloaded nginx_buildpack
   Downloading java_buildpack_4_37...
   Downloaded r_buildpack
   Downloading java_buildpack_offline_4_39...
   Downloaded java_buildpack_4_37
   Downloading java_buildpack_offline_4_47...
   Downloaded dotnet_core_buildpack_offline
   Downloading java_buildpack_offline_4_48_3...
   Downloaded dotnet_core_buildpack
   Downloading python_buildpack...
   Downloaded java_buildpack_offline_4_47
   Downloading ruby_buildpack...
   Downloaded nginx_buildpack_offline
   Downloading nodejs_buildpack...
   Downloaded java_buildpack_offline_4_48_3
   Downloading go_buildpack...
   Downloaded nodejs_buildpack
   Downloading tc_buildpack...
   Downloaded python_buildpack
   Downloading php_buildpack...
   Downloaded ruby_buildpack
   Downloading binary_buildpack...
   Downloaded java_buildpack_offline_4_39
   Downloaded go_buildpack
   Downloaded php_buildpack
   Downloaded binary_buildpack
   Downloaded tc_buildpack
   Cell ff3f7f85-2b37-4e45-bee3-c750fe848406 creating container for instance f0e66c15-fe01-4dd4-92d8-b321e7996fff
   Cell ff3f7f85-2b37-4e45-bee3-c750fe848406 successfully created container for instance f0e66c15-fe01-4dd4-92d8-b321e7996fff
   Downloading app package...
   Downloaded app package (170.4K)
NoAppDetectedError - An app was not successfully detected by any available buildpack
FAILED
```

I also have tried to start/stop the application through an apps manager, but that's not working. I've also tried to debug this issue by looking into the logs and I'm getting:

```html
2022-09-26T22:24:51.225-04:00 [STG/0] [ERR] None of the buildpacks detected a compatible application
2022-09-26T22:24:51.233-04:00 [STG/0] [OUT] Exit status 222
2022-09-26T22:24:51.867-04:00 [STG/0] [OUT] Cell ff3f7f85-2b37-4e45-bee3-c750fe848406 stopping instance f0e66c15-fe01-4dd4-92d8-b321e7996fff
2022-09-26T22:24:51.867-04:00 [STG/0] [OUT] Cell ff3f7f85-2b37-4e45-bee3-c750fe848406 destroying container for instance f0e66c15-fe01-4dd4-92d8-b321e7996fff
2022-09-26T22:24:51.909-04:00 [API/1] [ERR] Failed to stage build: staging failed
2022-09-26T22:24:52.218-04:00 [STG/0] [OUT] Cell ff3f7f85-2b37-4e45-bee3-c750fe848406 successfully destroyed container for instance f0e66c15-fe01-4dd4-92d8-b321e7996fff
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are you trying to push (`cf` pushes from the current directory or the directory you set with `-p`, either must point to the root of your app)? What buildpack do you expect to run?

Comment: I am trying to cf push my application. However I keep getting the "NoAppDetectedError - An app was not successfully detected by any available buildpack
FAILED" error message

Comment: @DanielMikusa I am trying to push a docker image, not a build pack.

Comment: You're not pushing it right, it thinks you're trying to push application files. You need to `cf push -o <image>` where `<image>` is the image you want to push like `docker.io/my-user/cool-app-img` or `gcr.io/cool-project/even-cooler-app-img`. The registry needs to be accessible from your CF instance. If for example, your CF is behind a firewall and without access to the Internet then it won't be able to deploy apps from DockerHub or GCR. Vise versa is true as well, if your app image is on an internal registry, that needs to be routable from CF.